# beta decay equation balance

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

Quark doesn't constitutes more fundamental particle and proton and neutron consist of quarks. Now come to beta decay.

> $n \rightarrow p + e^{-} + \bar{\nu}_e $

How can  an electron  emit from an neutron whereas electron is a fundamental particle? Is the electron created from gluon?

Comment: I've edited you decay equation to more accurately reflect the nature of the neutral lepton.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weak decay and it is mediated by a weak boson. In this case a $W^-$.

[image: betadec]

> [The Feynman diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#.CE.B2.E2.88.92_decay) for β−  decay of a neutron into a proton, electron, and electron antineutrino via an intermediate W−  boson.

At vertex level a down-quark is converted into a up-quark by the emission of virtual W-boson which decays to the electron electron-antineutrino pair. Charge is carried by the mediating boson.

Comment: so you are saying that quark can decay? Isn't it a fundamental one?

Comment: The weak interaction does not (fully) respect flavor. Weak interaction can convert quarks of one flavor to another.

Comment: @Raisa : Weak interactions involve left-handed particles. Left Quarks $d$ and $u$ are a SU(2) doublet, that is you have to consider the doublet left $(u,d)$ as a whole, exactly as a vector with $2$ dimensions, and SU(2) operations on this vector are allowed, for instance, a "rotation" could transform $u$ in $d$. Same thing for the doublet electron/ neutrino.

Comment: so quark is decaying and u  turning into d, therefore the electron formation comes from the energy releases by  up quark?